# How to create the Simplex Tableau in Latex

Tags: tables

Hey I need help to create the following tableau in LaTex[image]

I would be very thankful for your help!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Could you show us a complete code of what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you wish to typeset most of the cells' contents in math mode, the appearance of your screenshot notwithstanding.

Here's what I was able to come up with.

[image]

Speaking for myself, I can't say that this is a particularly appealing tableau.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\addto{\extrasngerman}{\renewcommand\tablename{Tab.}}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % automatic math mode
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\rotatebox' macro
\usepackage{multirow} % for '\multirow' macro
\newcommand\ec{\multicolumn{1}{c}{}} % "empty cell"
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}} % handy helper macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|C|CCC|CCC|C|C|}
\cline{3-8}
\ec & & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Nichtbasisvariable} 
      & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Basisvariable} & \ec & \ec \\
\cline{3-10}
\ec & & x_1 & \dots & x_{n-m} & x_{n-m+1} & \dots & x_n & F & b_i \\
\hline
\multirow{3.5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\mytab{Basis-\\variable}}}
& x_{n-m+1} & a_{11} & \dots & a_{1,n-m} & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0 & b_1 \\
& \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
& x_{n} & a_{m1} & \dots & a_{m,n-m} & 0 & \dots & 1 & 0 & b_m \\
\hline
\ec & & -c_1 & \dots & -c_{n-m} & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1 & \mytab{akt.\\Zfw.} \\
\cline{3-10}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which comment makes sure that the both cells on the left have nothing above or beneath?

Comment: @AndreasHofer - Not a command, but the fact that the argument of `\cline` doesn’t start with 1.

Comment: Ahh okey thanks a lot!!!